# Is it better to incorporate motion sensor and sound files in google assistant - or a python based audio chatbot programme?

Tags: audio, dialogflow-es, chatbot, sensors

I want to incorporate a few new things in an audio chatbot.  Can I please check the best way to do it?
- I want to record actor's voices to replace the chatbot's default computerised voice
- I want to include sound files that play on demand (and with variety, so the file that plays depends on user choices) - is that possible and if so is there much delay before they start playing?
- I would also like to use sensor motion to start the program, so that the chatbot automatically says hello and starts a conversation when a user enters a room, rather than the user having to say 'hello google, can I talk to...blah blah' to activate the chatbot.

- Thus far I've been using dialogflow to build natural language processing chatbots.  Does dialogflow have the capacity to do all this, or should I use another programme linked to it as well?  Or, for this sort of functionality would it be better to build a chatbot using python - and does anybody know any open source versions?

Comment: here are two voice libraries ... 
    Rhasspy (pronounced RAH-SPEE) is an open source, fully offline voice assistant toolkit for many languages that works well with Home Assistant, Hass.io, and Node-RED.
    https://rhasspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
    https://github.com/synesthesiam/rhasspy

    Jasper is an open source platform for developing always-on, voice-controlled applications
    https://jasperproject.github.io/
    https://github.com/jasperproject/jasper-client

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have the chatbot start a conversation without the user saying "Okay, Google. Talk to..". This has been done so that Google Assistant cannot be triggered without the user activating it themselves.

As for using sound files, you can record parts of your conversation and use these files in your conversation using SSML. With SSML you can edit what your assistant says using simple code. The [audio tag](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/reference/ssml#audio) is what you need to play sound files.